# Neccessary Condition involving Sylow-Subgroups for $p$-Solvability

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G = AB$ and let $P \unlhd A$, where $P \in Syl_p(G)$. If $P$ permutes with all Sylow $q$-subgroups of $B$ with $q \ne p$, then $G$ is $p$-solvable.

Any suggestions on how to proof?

Comment: Is $A\cap B =e$ ?

Comment: No, not necessarily.